# Vapor 3/Fluent for Postgres: How do I make a SELECT DISTINCT query?

Tags: postgresql, fluent, vapor

I'd like to query a model such that Fluent generates SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(<my columns>) * FROM my_table...
```

How do I do that?

Comment: If you search inside your project, there is a 'distinct' protocol, but I can't see how to use it. You could try a raw query until the docs catch up.

Comment: @Nick yeah, saw that protocol, couldn't figure out how to make use of it :/ Raw I think requires me to write a bunch of gross code, so trying to avoid it... but asked some of the Vapor folks on Twitter, so maybe they'll have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh.

So, ended up having to use a raw query. You can do the same with:

```
let distinctModels = req.withPooledConnection(to: .psql) { (conn) -> Future<[MyModel]> in
    conn.raw("SELECT DISTINCT ON(<my columns>) * FROM <my_table> INNER JOIN <another_table> ON <some_condition> WHERE <conditions>")
        .all(decoding: MyModel.self)
}
```

Where `req` is of type `Request`. The function `withPooledConnection` will return a future of your models – just make sure you decode them!